# Complex heatmap barplot ordering

Tags: r, heatmap

I have generated a fairly simple oncoprint using Complexheatmaps. Is anyone able to tell me the way the default top annotation barplot is ordered. My rows are ordered specifically to group shared genes but this is not followed in the stacked barplot. I was hoping the barplot ordering would follow the row orders so that these would match. I can't seem to find an answer to this in the vignette. Do I have to write a separate heatmap annotation to solve this (being a novice I am afraid to admit this may take me a little while!!)
Many thanks,
. [Oncoprint image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHMQw.png)